# Quickblox configuration for a new environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, quickblox

I am using the Quickblox ruby gem. Now I want to link to a different Quickblox account (development, beta, production...etc). In their [document](http://quickblox.com/developers/QuickBlox_Ruby_Gem#Configuration)

They use config.yml, so should I configure my different environments there?

My config.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
  quickblox:
    application_id: 12345
    auth_key: xxxxx
    auth_secret: xxxxx
    server: api.quickblox.com
    user_owner_id: 1

 development:
   <<: *defaults

 test:
   <<: *defaults
```

My attempt did not work.

Comment: What kind of errors do you got?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's the limitation for [Quickblox Gem](https://github.com/QuickBlox/QuickBlox-RubyGem), they hard coded the yaml file loading format. I updated their Gem and now [it](https://github.com/linxinda/QuickBlox-RubyGem) works.